# How often do Double ratchet in Signal protocol update DH ratchet key

Tags: diffie-hellman, protocol-design, signal-protocol

I'm trying to understand the specification behind [doubleratchet](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/) algorithm, *item 2.4. Double Ratchet*.

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Ratchet_Algorithm):

> A client renews session key material in interaction with the remote
> peer using Diffie–Hellman ratchet whenever possible, otherwise
> independently by using a hash ratchet.

- What does impede Signal protocol from updating DH ratchet for every message?
- Does it mean that Signal protocol **not guarantee future secrecy** (aka backward secrecy) for a chain when a symmetric key is compromised (and adversary can derive new keys for future messages) until DH ratchet updates a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - What does impede Signal protocol from updating DH ratchet for every message?

The main obstacles are rooted in the striking of a balance between efficiency & efficacy. That balance is heavily influenced by the asynchronous setting of the protocol. Where peer $A$ could create a new public key with each message they send to peer $B$, the self-healing ([post-compromise security](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/221.pdf)) property of the channel won't be activated if it's peer $B$'s secrets which have been compromised. As such, channel-wise self-healing requires both parties to contribute new independent secrets to the current state of the channel, which can be arbitrarily delayed in the [asynchronous](https://www.yac.com/blog/asynchronous-communication) setting. Therefore, $A$ contributing new independent secrets multiple times before $B$ has responded with their own, incurs the same updating costs but with limited (potentially zero) security benefit.

<sup>*See [Messaging Layer Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/272078/289428) for other approaches to resolving efficiency issues.*</sup>

---

> - Does it mean that Signal protocol not guarantee future secrecy (aka backward secrecy) for a chain when a symmetric key is compromised (and adversary can derive new keys for future messages) until DH ratchet updates a key?

The term *"post-compromise security"* is preferred when discussing this self-healing property of a security context. As for what is actually compromised when a "symmetric key" is compromised: that depends on which symmetric key is being considered. The short answer is that the Diffie-Hellman ratchet is the ***only*** thing in the protocol which provides post-compromise security. As for the longer answer:

[image: Double Ratchet Key Schedule Diagram]

<sup>**Figure 1 |** [Diagram](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/doubleratchet.pdf#section*.7) of Double Ratchet key derivations.</sup>

Consider the above diagram. Each red-ish, pill-shaped node which isn't directly under the "Ratchet" column represents a symmetric key. Let's separate them into two relative types: a $K_\text{seed}$ type, & a $K_\text{derived}$ type.

Any symmetric key is a $K_\text{derived}$ type if it is directly under **or** to the right of & under, another symmetric key, which would be a $K_\text{seed}$ type. A $K_\text{derived}$ key is compromised if a $K_\text{seed}$ key is compromised & the two keys are not separated by a Diffie-Hellman ratchet of the channel state.

Said another way. If no Diffie-Hellman ratchet is performed: compromising a root key (denoted `RK` in the diagram), compromises all subsequent chain & message keys; compromising a chain key (denoted `CK` in the diagram), compromises all subsequent chain & message keys; and, compromising a message key (denoted `An` & `Bn` in the diagram, where the letter `n` is an incrementing numeral), only compromises that message key.

Comment: I think you might need to include the Trust On the First Use (TOFU) problem.